# ¿Cómo asegurar integridad de datos al insertar registros relacionados en dos tablas en una aplicación web?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, aplicación-web, asp, stored-procedure

En una aplicación web que he desarrollado, estoy teniendo problemas de integridad en la base de datos cuando realizo INSERT en dos tablas diferentes que tienen información relacionada y se interrumpe la conexión a internet en medio del proceso. Por ejemplo al registrar una nueva factura, primero realizo el INSERT en tabla de facturas y a continuación los sucesivos INSERT en la tabla de items. El problema surge cuando la conexión a internet se interrumpe luego procesar el primer INSERT y antes o durante la segunda serie de INSERT, lo que ocasiona que se registre una factura que no tiene ítems o que tiene una cantidad parcial de los ítems que debería tener. Lógicamente la tasa de ocurrencia de este tipo de problema es muy baja y en general puedo reparar la integridad manualmente, pero quisiera que me ayuden a identificar cuáles serían las "buenas prácticas" recomendadas para lidiar con esta cuestión. Supongo que lo ideal sería poder mandar todo el paquete de información en una misma solicitud a la base de datos y resolver los INSERT en las tablas con un procedimiento almacenado o algo similar, pero no estoy seguro ya que nunca he realizado uno. La aplicación está desarrollada en ASP y la base de datos es MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución consiste en utilizar **transacciones**. Este mecanismo de las bases de datos permite realizar más de una consulta sucesivamente, pero esperando hasta que terminen todas para "confirmar" (`COMMIT`) los cambios. Hasta que no se realiza el `COMMIT` los cambios no se aplican. Si se produce algún error durante las consultas, se puede cancelar (`ROLLBACK`) la transacción, y la base de datos queda como antes de comenzar.

Pasos:

- Comenzar la transacción
- Realizar las inserciones de datos
- Si todo ha ido bien, confirmar la transacción (`COMMIT`).
- Si se produce algún error durante las inserciones, revertir los
  cambios (`ROLLBACK`).

Ejemplo SQL:

```
SET autocommit = 0; sin esto, 
BEGIN TRANSACTION

INSERT #1

... 

INSERT #N
```

Si todas las queries han ido bien:

```
COMMIT
```

Pero si se ha producido algún error:

```
ROLLBACK
```

---

Para poder controlar correctamente el proceso, te recomiendo usar excepciones. Si usas `PDO` se puede configurar el conector para que lance una excepción cuando una consulta falle. Si capturas una excepción, realizas el rollback.

Comment: Excelente gontrollez! Voy a trabajar sobre tu sugerencia y luego te cuento. Gracias :)